# about ctors and inheritance

Tags: c++

Im kinda new to C++.
I have an assignment where I should implement c class' default ctor and cctor so that theyll print "c::ctor" and "c::cctor" respectively.
I have no idea of how to deal with this, help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class a {
public:
    a(const char* sname)
        :  _sname(sname) {
        cout << "a::ctor" << endl;
    }
    a(const a& s) { cout << "a::copy ctor" << endl; }
    virtual ~a() { cout << "a::dtor " << endl; }
    void f1() { cout << "a::f1()" << endl; f2(); }
    virtual void f2() = 0;
private:
    string _sname;
};

class b1 : virtual public a {
public:
    b1(const char* saname, const char* ssname)
        : _sname1(saname), a(ssname) {
    }
    b1(const b1& b1) : a(b1) { cout << "b1 :: copy ctor << endl"; }
    ~b1() { cout << "b1::dtor" << endl; }
    virtual void f1() { cout << "b1::f1()" << endl; }
    virtual void f2() { cout << "b1::f2()" << endl; }
    virtual void f3() { cout << "b1::f3()" << endl; }
private:
    string _sname1;
};

class b2 : virtual public a {
public:
    b2(const char* saname, const char* ssname)
        : _sname2(saname), a(ssname) {
        cout << "b2::ctor" << endl;
    }
    b2(const b2& b2) : a(b2) { cout << "b2::copy ctor" << endl; }
    ~b2() { cout << "b2::dtor" << endl; }
    virtual void f3() { f1(); cout << "b2::f3()" << endl; }
private:
    string _sname2;
};

class c : public b1, public b2 {
public:
    c();
    c(const c& c);
    ~c() { cout << "c::dtor" << endl; }
    virtual void f1() { a::f1(); cout << "c::f1()" << endl; }
    void f3() { cout << "c::f3()" << endl; }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand.  The classes `a1, b1, b2` all have copy constructors that satisfy your requirements.  Why can't you do the same with class `c`?  Example: `c(const c& variable) {cout << "c::copy constructor\n";}`

Comment: Compiler says that theres no default ctor for class a when I try to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of virtual inheritance, things are more complicated for the constructors and destructors. The constructors and the destructors of the virtual base class `a` should also be called in the `c` class since the compiler cannot choose between `b1` or `b2` to build the (unique) `a` part in the `c` object. For the destructor, the compilers handles things to call the destructor of `b1`, the destructor of `b2` and the destructor of `a`.

So you should implement

```
class c : public b1, public b2 {
public:
  c() : b1("", ""), b2("", ""), a("") {}
  c(const c& src) : b1(src), b2(src), a(src) {}
};
```

In general, you should try to avoid virtual inheritance when not necessary. But it is a good exercise to understand how it works.